# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) React Native_camera

Tags: react-native-camera

I want to use react-native-camera in expo but I get this error.-> **Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)** Here is code.

```
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Modal, View, Pressable, Text, SafeAreaView, Button, Image, 
PushNotificationIOS } from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
import {shareAsync} from 'expo-sharing';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';


export default function App() {

  let cameraRef = useRef();
  const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState();
  const [hasMediaLibraryPermission, setHasMediaLibraryPermission] = useState();
  const [photo, setPhoto]  = useState();

  useEffect(()=>{
    (async ()=>{
      const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      constMediaLibraryPermission = await MediaLibrary.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      setHasCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === "granted");
      setHasMediaLibraryPermission(MediaLibraryPermission.status === "granted");

    })();
  },[]);

  if (hasCameraPermission === undefined){
    return <Text> Requesting permissions...</Text>
  } else if (!hasCameraPermission){
    return <Text> Permission for camera not granted. Please change this in settinr.</Text>
  }

  let takePic = async () => {
    let options = {
      quality :1,
      base64: true,
      exif : false
    };

    let newPhoto = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
    setPhoto(newPhoto);
  };

  if(photo){
    let sharePic = () => {
      shareAsync(photo.uri).then(() => {
        setPhoto(undefined);
      });

    };
    let savePhoto = () => {
      MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri).then(() =>{
        setPhoto(undefined);
      });

    };

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
        <Image style = {styles.preview} source = {{uri: "data:image/jpg;base64," + 
photo.base64}}/>
        <Button title = "share" onPress = {sharePic}/>
        {hasMediaLibraryPermission ? <Button title = "save" onPress = {savePhoto}/>:undefined}
         <Button title = "Discard" onPress = {()=> setPhoto(undefined)}/>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }

  return (
<Camera style={styles.container} ref = {cameraRef}>
  <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
    <Button title = "Takc Pic" onPress = {takePic} />
  </View>
  <StatusBar style="auto" />
</Camera>
  );

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
  },
   buttonContainer:{
    backgroundColor :'#fff',
    alignSelf:'flex-end'
  },
  preview:{
    alignSelf:'stretch',
    flex:1
  }
});
```

So I try 'catch-throw', but I didn't solve this problem. Because 'try' is necessary.

I checked other questions and answers, but I didn't find a solution.

How can I solve this error?